# How to check the availability of the TADODataSet in a dbgrid?

Tags: sql-server, delphi, exception, grid, tadodataset

I use a DBGrid on my VCL Form. The grid is populated with the records, coming from a `TADOConnection` query. Semantically it looks like this:

- Establish a connection to the database (SQL Server);
- Fetch some records into a `TADODataSet` dataset;
- Connect dataset with a `TDataSource` object;
- Connect a `DataSource` object to the DBGrid.

My grid does the immediate post, which means the edited data is immediately posted to the database. Everything works fine, until the connection is closed (the network goes down, the laptop's lid is closed, etc.)

When the connection is lost, I cannot edit records in Grid, which causes `EOleException` (*TCP PRovider: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host*) abd `EDatabaseError` (*Communication link failure*).

I want to catch the connectivity loss and re-establish connection, but I do not know how. I checked all data-specific events of the Grid, but the problem arises much earlier than any of the grid's events.

I believe that the problem is at the dataset level, but I don't know how to catch the exception. Does anyone know how to check dataset availability? Then I could write some code to re-connect. Something like this:

```
if not Assigned(DataSet) then
    //reconnect
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You could possibly check DataSource.DataSet.Connection.Connected

Comment: [OnEditError](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Data.DB.TDataSet.OnEditError) wouldn't help?

Comment: I have never found a way of re-establishing a lost ADO connection which is 100% reliable.  The best solution I have found is to run a background thread which periodically tests the connection (by calling some low-overhead task on the server).  If the test fails, then save the dataset data locally using ADO- briefcase mode, restart the application, and if the connection can be opened, restore the local data, apply it to the server, etc.

Comment: Thank you all involved. I took a week and dove deeply into FireDAC. As a result I've migrated all my apps to FireDAC and truly became its addict :-)
@Dave, @Victoria, it didn't help. It is non-trivial to catch `EDatabaseError` and `EOleException` in an ADO app. I tried nearly all event handlers of nearly all components and nothing helped. FireDAC has a built-in functionality to recover broken connections, so I am with it now. #FireDACrules

Comment: It’s not “non-trivial” at all to catch those errors. You don’t use event handlers on the components to catch them; you use exception handling